# Sorting numbers from an array into columns and rows in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, random

Im trying to figure out how i would be able to properly display numbers from an array in columns and rows.

here is my function so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int talfoljd()
{
    int i;
    int kolumn = 1;
    int rad = 1;
    int nummer[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        nummer[i] = (rand() % 900) + 1;

        for (rad = 0; rad < 10; rad++)
            for (kolumn = 0; kolumn < 10; kolumn++)
                for (rad = 0; rad < 10; rad++)
                {
                    for (kolumn = 0; kolumn < 10; kolumn++)
                    {
                        printf("%d ", nummer[i++]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
        return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what i get as an output.

```
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
```

So my problem is not to get numbers to appear in columns and rows it is to get the numbers from the array to appear in the right spot. As for now only the first number shows up.

Comment: Change this: `printf("%d ", nummer[i++]);` to this: `printf("%d ", nummer[i]);`

Comment: use `srand(time(NULL));` once to randomize the seed. also, change`nummer[i++])` to `nummer[i])`

Comment: Are you sure that this code will compile ?

Comment: Yes, it will compile. I tried to do the changes Rizier123 gave me, I ended up with the first number being right and all the other ones being -858993460.

Comment: Made an answer, is that what your looking for? if not please explain more what your goal is!

Comment: Yes that is what i was looking for, thank you! my code is pretty much just me doing trial and error until i got something that i thought was on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I think your program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 100

void randomNumberTable() {

    int count;
    int nummers[SIZE];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        nummers[count] = (rand() % 900) + 1;

    for(count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {

        if(count % 10 == 0)
            printf("\n");

        printf("%4d ", nummers[count]);

    }

}

int main() {

    printf("Random Number Table:\n");
    randomNumberTable();

    return 0;

}
```

possible output:

```
Random Number Table:

 194  310  641  512  184  198  647  342  895  682
 711  453  232  604  129  179  378  639  616   83
 499  779  450   99  553   88   80  754  633  235
 248  183  625  635  196  887   44  784  265  283
 586  133  484   40  372  800  852  794  259  558
 112  330   96   74  394  627  215  322  448  691
 896  880  109  243  505   35  480  476  594  651
 525  612  441   16  852  721  429  125  838  779
 281  344  645  592  301  297  355  515  573   53
 766  549  569  384   34  796  863  385  864  889
```

Comment: Yes this works! now all i need to know is why it works, what is it that i did so terrible wrong? Im am trying to learn and i dont just wanna copy your code

Comment: @user3529167 Nice that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is containing extra two outer for loops which is unnecessary. The second point is your code is not coming back to the random function generator second time. Hence it is ending up printing the first generated number it self. I think your program should look something like this:

```
   i = 0;
   for (rad = 0; rad < 10; rad++)
   {
      nummer[i] = (rand() % 900) + 1;
       for (kolumn = 0; kolumn < 10; kolumn++)
        {
           printf("%d ", nummer[i++]);
         }
       printf("\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn, then you must learn to mentally step through your code to see if the control path is indeed what you wanted. Doing that would have revealed that after having only once called the random number generator, you now wanted to print out the whole array. You would also learn that the the innermost loop with 'rad' loop variable would be overwriting the outer loop 'rad' loop variable.

To learn to mentally step through the code, you can use a debugger to physically step through the code. It would have shown you the above observations.

To learn, study "good code" from other people, such as the examples above. Good luck - "learn long and prosper"